# Problem with schema validation using Postman

Tags: validation, postman, schema

Body of my req:

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name abc",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "something"
  },
...
]
```

I am trying to validate it like below:

```
var schema = {
  "type": "array",
  "properties": {
    "postId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
     "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$"
    },
    "body": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "postId",
    "id",
    "name",
    "email",
    "body"
  ]
};

pm.test('Schemat jest poprawny', function() {
  pm.expect(tv4.validate(jsonData, schema)).to.be.true;
});
```

The test is ok even if I change for example id type for string or email pattern for invalid one.

What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend moving away from tv4 for schema validations and use the built-in [jsonSchema](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#response-assertion-api-available-in-the-test-scripts) function, as this uses [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv).

Apart from that, your schema didn't look right and was missing the validation against the `object`, it looks like it was doing it against the `array`.

This might help you out:

```
let schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
            "postId",
            "id",
            "name",
            "email",
            "body"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "postId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "email": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$"
            },
            "body": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}

pm.test("Schemat jest poprawny", () => {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema)
})
```

Comment: Can you accept this answer and upvote if this help you.